# Java 8 stream conditional check

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list= new List<Map<String,Object>>();
System.out.println(list.stream().mapToInt(i ->  (Integer)i.get("amount")).sum());
```

I have a List of items like above. I am trying to print the sum of amount which would be an key inside the map. This works fine. But i am just wondering if there is way if i can just check if the map contains that key in this  one line code. Any way to include an if condition of map.containsKey here?

Comment: What do you expect if it does not? Should it default to `0`?

Comment: Yes, or i just need not to take that map for the summation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for `getOrDefault` to be used as:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(i ->  (Integer)i.getOrDefault("amount", 0)).sum());
```

which when the `key` doesn't exist returns `0` as the default value.

Comment: This will satisfy my requirement . But still wondering if we can add a conditional logic  here?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer sure, you can insert `.filter(i -> i.containsKey("amount"))` before the `map` step. But that’s so trivial that I’m not sure whether this is your actual question.

Comment: @Holger , while Naman's answer solves the problem i was facing in a way , your answer is what exactly i was asked :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Stream.filter` to get only the maps which has key `amount` for the summation.

```
System.out.println(list.stream().filter(m -> m.containsKey("amount")).mapToInt(i ->  (Integer)i.get("amount")).sum());
```

Comment: But this did not work. If i change the key from "amount" to "amounts" in  one of the map item in the list while keeping all others as "amount" . It breaks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Stream::filter` in combination with `Objects::nonNull`

```
list.stream()
    .map(map -> map.get("amount"))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToInt(Integer.class::cast)
    .sum()
```